# ruby date validation on wrong input

Tags: ruby, date

Im a newbie to rails and I need your help on this one.

On the code below, if the first input is wrong and the second one is correct, the expression evaluates the first input. 
I would like that the user input is always evaluated.

```
require 'date'

puts "x is not a valid date" 
until (x = gets.chomp) == ((x.match(/\d{4}-\d{1,2}-\d{1,2}$/).to_s &&Date.strptime(x, '%Y-%m-%d')rescue false) ==true)
```

Comment: ty for the input, its much appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, you should try to separate your data inout logic from data validation and later processing. That way, your methods concern themselves with only one thing each, which makes them much easier to reason about and thus more robust.

Here, we are introducing a `valid_date_string?` method which checks if the passed `input` object is a valid date string.

```
require 'date'

def valid_date_string?(input)
  # First, we check that the given input is of the expected type.
  # We do this here explicitly since we are validating a String. Most
  # of the time, you would rely on duck typing instead.
  return false unless input.is_a?(String)

  # Then, we ensure roughly valid syntax (i.e. it looks like a date)
  return false unless input =~ /\A\d+-\d+-\d+\z/

  # Then, we "parse" it and split it into an array of year, month, day...
  parts = input.split('-').map(&:to_i)
  # ...and validate that this represents a valid date
  Date.valid_date?(*parts)
end
```

In this solution, I took care not to rely on Exceptions for program flow since this is usually frowned upon as it can result in undetected bugs and has poor performance.

We can then use this method in some input loop to ask the user to input some value

```
def get_valid_date
  loop do
    input = gets.chomp
    return input if valid_date_string?(input)

    # Here, the user entered an invalid date. We can now do our
    # error handling and try again.
    puts "Invalid date given. Please try again..."
  end
end

my_valid_date_string = get_valid_date
```

Comment: Honestly you provided a better solution +1

Comment: thank you @Holger ! This helped me clarify more things !

Answer (score 0):

I would approach this problem as follows:

```
# date_test.rb

def date_input
  puts "Please enter a date (format YYYY-MM-DD):"
  d = gets.chomp
  if d =~ /\d{4}-\d{1,2}-\d{1,2}$/
    puts "You entered: #{d}"
  else
    puts "#{d} is not a valid date."
    date_input
  end
end

date_input
```

Explanation:

- prompt to enter a date (specifying the expected format)
- gets and chomp the user input
- validate the format

  - if valid, puts the date
  - if not valid, puts the error and start again

When you run it:

```
$ ruby date_test.rb
Please enter a date (format YYYY-MM-DD):
invalid date
invalid date is not a valid date.
Please enter a date (format YYYY-MM-DD):
2017-10-13
You entered: 2017-10-13
$
```

Comment: Thank you @mabe02 ,the code looks like below and it validates the date format and an existing date:
require 'date'
def date_input
  puts "Please enter a date (format YYYY-MM-DD):"
  d = gets.chomp
  if (d =~ /\d{4}-\d{1,2}-\d{1,2}$/ && Date.strptime(d, '%Y-%m-%d')rescue false)
    puts "You entered: #{d}"
  else
    puts "#{d} is not a valid date."
    date_input
  end
end
date_input

Comment: Hey @GeorgeConstantin, did you find this answer useful? Does it solve your question? If not, can you tell me how it can be improved to be accepted?

Comment: Would you upvote and accept the answer then? :) You are welcome!

Comment: @mabe22, i did, but it says that i`m under 15 points and it wont be displayed, but it will be counted.

Comment: Don't worry. Thanks

Comment: Your solution does not reject invalid (but syntactically correct) dates like `2017-65-84`. Also, relying in recursion for error handling is not only slow but also results in some potentially significant memory pressure.